# mysql select js variable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, variables

Hey I wanna know if something like this is possible?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = ".echo"monthS";."  );
```

Obviously the syntax is wrong (because it doesn't work), but basically I want to select some data from my database where equal to the variable which happen to be a JS variable in my JS file. I know you can't assign a js variable to a PHP, unless you use AJAX, but when I use ajax, it returns an empty string first, runs the php and then it gives me the value of the variable, but by then my php script already ran. So was wondering if I could echo the variable.

I'm not using any submit or hidden post method because it isn't necessary in what I'm trying to create. So I need to find a way for PHP to recognize the variable and make the query. PLEASE help me. Thank a lot.

my JS:

```
   var date = new Date();
 var month = date.getMonth();
 var day = date.getDay();
 var monthDate = date.getDate();
 var monthNow= date.getMonth(); 
 var monthNow2;
 var current = 1;
 var first_date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);     
 var start_day = first_date.getDay();
 var start_day2;
 var first_date2;
 var weekday;
 var day_selected;
 var day_selectedTxt;
 var monthNowTxt;
 var dayNum; 
 var out;
 var monthS;

 var calenderMonths = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 
                        'October', 'November', 'December']; 

 var calenderDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ];

 var daysInMonths = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];




function currentDate(){
        var first_day = first_date.getDay() +1;
        document.getElementById("monthElement").innerHTML = calenderMonths[month];

        for( var days = 1; days <= daysInMonths[month]; days++) {


            document.getElementById("day"+ first_day).innerHTML = days;
            first_day++;

        }
            //current date

            if( month === monthNow) {
        monthDateNow = start_day +monthDate;
            var today = document.getElementById("day"+ monthDateNow);
             today.setAttribute('class', today.getAttribute('class') + ' current'); 

            }
            start_day2 = start_day; 
            monthNow2 = monthNow;

                monthS = calenderMonths[monthNow];
                $.get('load2.php', {month:monthS} );
                                //where i made the ajax get

}
```

my PHP:

```
<?php

Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);



        $monthS = $_GET['month'];



    // Connect to MySQL
         if ( !( $database = mysql_connect( "localhost",
            "root", "" ) ) )                      
            die( "Could not connect to database </body></html>" );

    // open Events database
         if ( !mysql_select_db( "Events", $database ) )
            die( "Could not open Events database </body></html>" );


            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = .'monthS'.") 
                    or die ('Error updating database because: '.mysql_error());;


            $daysArray = Array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $daysArray[] =  $row['DayNum']; }
            $length = count($daysArray);

            echo "function test() { ";

                for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
            echo "var active = document.getElementById('day'+".$daysArray[$i].");
             active.setAttribute('class', active.getAttribute('class') + ' event');  ";
}       
            echo "}";



?>
```

And in my HTML i have `<body onload="currentDate(); test(); " class ="home">` and other code ofc, I just posted that cause the rest wasn't necessary.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information and code for what you are trying to do...

Comment: you're completely mis-understanding ajax.... you use an ajax call on your client to talk to the server, send over the JS variable as a standard form/query parameter. the scsript runs, uses that parameter to do whatever it has to, and returns the data.

Comment: Which is your js variable

Comment: but ajax only returns an empty string. This is what i have in my js file $.get('load2.php', {month:monthS} ); And I'm calling it in my php file using $monthS = $_GET['month'];

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala monthS is the js variable

Comment: You need to provide us some code to understand what are you doing for ajax

Comment: If used without ajax just type js variable between two .variable.  Like month_ = ".monthS."  this should work

Comment: There are many bugs in your code

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Maybe cause I left out some code. could I email you the files?

Comment: You can post it in your question givin mail ids are against forum rules I guess

Comment: I shall get back to you tomorrow morning it's 2 am here in India feeling sleepy

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala checked it out?

Comment: is this column name correct `Month_`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code,

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$monthS = $_GET['month'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posted_events WHERE Month_ = '$monthS'");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $daysArray[] =  $row['DayNum']; 
}

$length = count($daysArray);

for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) 
{ 
    echo $daysArray[$i];
}       

?>
```

MySql is not suggested would recommend you move to mysqli or pdo